# How to exclude one object/option while processing a state file on multiple objects

Tags: devops, salt-stack

I'm downloading certain microservices in a folder at **D:\SaltDownload**. I'm storing all of these files on my minions and the contents of the folder would look like this:

```
serviceA.zip
serviceB.zip
serviceC.zip
serviceD.zip
```

Now I'm extracting the contents of folder using the below code:

```
extract_zip_file_{{servicename}}:
   archive.extracted:
      - name: {{edir}}
      - source: {{dfulln}}
      - enforce_toplevel: False
      - require:
        - cmd: download_zip_file
```

The name and source used above are dynamic and will point to the D:\SaltDownload. My problem is that now for certain condition I want to extract 3 services - *serviceA, serviceB and serviceC* but I want to **exclude serviceD**. Next I'm deleting few files and some more processing on these files. In all of these files I'm using the same folder path. But I want to exclude serviceD.

Is there any way in salt where I can exclude serviceD?

I saw the exclude statement document on salt website but that is for excluding SLS file and here I want to exclude one of the option/object?

Comment: What is the condition for a particular service to be excluded? Is it machine (minion) specific? What's the logic of exclusion if we take Saltstack out of the picture?

Comment: If given an option I would like to exclude it via it's name. 
For e.g:
exclude:
  - name: serviceD

Comment: um, please post a full example of how you are filling out the variables. there are a number of details that are missing from your ask that are important to the question.

Comment: Presumably you are looping over a list to generate `dfulln` etc. Just add a condition to skip the one you want when you want to, so it is never defined in the first place.

Comment: @OrangeDog yeah that was my assumption as well but wanted to be sure that is what they were doing. been bit to often by incorrect assumptions based on someones unposted code.